# How can I disable text selection on a jquery draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have several draggables on my page.  When I start dragging one, it moves just fine, but the other elements on the page are getting highlighted/selected from my cursor.

I noticed that the draggle demos on the jquery UI website seemed to work just fine.  Does anyone have any ideas why the text is being selected on my site during dragging?

This is the code I'm using (seems pretty standard to me):

```
$('.dragger').draggable(
{
 'helper': 'clone',
 'revert': true
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [this demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) sources, for example:

```
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

**edit**
A [post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disableselection) from jquery forum explaining the situation around `disableSelection`. Looks like it's 'undocumented' for a long time already.

Comment: I found that the disableSelection() doesn't do anything if I have:

'helper': 'clone'

If I remove the 'helper' argument, then no selection occurs.  Anyone know how to disable selection when there is a clone helper?

Comment: @user463604 'helper: clone' means that element is cloned, so no event handles associated with it. But you can execute _disableSelection_ again once element is dropped (if I understand your problem correctly).

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is ancient, but since I've found a possible solution I've decided to post it anyway.  Simply add this line to your parent DIV (I know, 'bind' is depreciated.  Sue me.):

```
$('#parentdiv').bind('mousedown', function(event) { event.preventDefault() });
```

Selections don't happen because mousedown events are never completed. I've tested this with multiple DIVs and it seems to work!